# Yii::configure does not work in module init()

Tags: php, yii2

I have a module calls API, and i want to load config file for it. The guide says that i have to use function \Yii::configure. I use it, but it doesn't apply any new configs. And i tried to use array instead config file, the result is same

```
class API extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\client\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

//        \Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config/main.php'));

        \yii::configure($this, [
            'components' => [
                'user' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\UserTest',
                    'identityClass' => 'api\client\models\User',
                ],
            ]
        ]);

        echo \yii::$app->user->className();

        die();
    }
}
```

How I can override config in my module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You have to use setComponents method of Yii::$app

```
    Yii::$app->setComponents(
        [
            'errorHandler'=>[
                'errorAction'=>'forum/forum/error',
                'class'=>'yii\web\ErrorHandler',
            ],     
            'user' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\User',
                'identityClass' => 'app\modules\profile\models\User',
            ],
        ]
    );
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Didn't it give you errors? Your casing are wrong and so instead of "yii" in small letters use "Yii" capitalized

```
class API extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\client\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init(); 

        \Yii::configure($this, [
            'components' => [
                'user' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\UserTest',
                    'identityClass' => 'api\client\models\User',
                ],
            ]
        ]);

        echo \Yii::$app->user->className();

        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you do `var_dump(\Yii::$app->user);` to see whats happening?

Comment: basically you want your identity class, don't you? use updated answer ` echo \Yii::$app->user->identity->className();`

Comment: what does `var_dump(\Yii::$app->user->identity);` printt?

Comment: did you seem my comment above? whats is the dump?

Comment: Oh! My changes was not saved (just realized now. So check updated post

Comment: Did you delet your comment? You said it worked. For me its working fine. If its not working then you have something wrong. Can you edit post and add your current code? (Do not remove old ones)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to override the application components here. I'd use @StefanoMtangoo trick but to set the component to the Module itself instead of `Yii::$app`:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->setComponents([
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii2tech\filedb\Connection',
            'path' => '@app/builder/data',
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Then the tricky part is to differentiate between any app's components and your module's own components. For example if my Module had a model extending [yii\db\ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html) I'd override its [getDB()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#getDb()-detail) as follow *(original code [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/510cd3541d32331653913a149c908c9e579a7cc2/framework/db/ActiveRecord.php#L131))*:

```
public static function getDb()
{
    return Yii::$app->getModule('api')->get('db');
    // instead of: return Yii::$app->getDb();
}
```

So whatever the app that is using my module has or hasn't a `db` component it won't matter.